# How do I make my custom widget appear in my splitter using Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm still learning Kivy nuances, & I just can't seem to make my Chessboard widget appear in my splitter. I substituted a working button widget in the splitter for my custom widget, but it's not acting the same. What am I doing wrong?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.splitter import Splitter
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

kivy.require('2.0.0')

class ChessBoardWidget(Widget):  # FloatLayout
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChessBoardWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0, 1, 0, 1)
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=(self.width, self.height), pos=self.pos)

        self.add_widget(
            Image(source="./data/images/chess-pieces/DarkerGreenGreyChessBoard.png", pos=self.pos,
                  size_hint=(1, 1), keep_ratio=True, allow_stretch=True))


class SplitterGui(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SplitterGui, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'horizontal'

        split1_boxlayout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        split1 = Splitter(sizable_from='bottom', min_size=100, max_size=1000)
        chessboard_widget = ChessBoardWidget()  # was s1_button = Button(text='s1', size_hint=(1, 1)) WORKED!
        s3_button = Button(text='s3', size_hint=(1, 1))
        split1.add_widget(chessboard_widget)  # was split1.add_widget(s1_button) WORKED!
        split1_boxlayout.add_widget(split1)
        split1_boxlayout.add_widget(s3_button)
        self.add_widget(split1_boxlayout)

        split2 = Splitter(sizable_from='left', min_size=100, max_size=1000)
        s2_button = Button(text='s2', size_hint=(.1, 1))
        split2.add_widget(s2_button)
        self.add_widget(split2)


class SplitterTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SplitterGui()  # root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SplitterTestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ChessBoardWidget` is being drawn, it's just not where you expect it. Three things to keep in mind:

1. Using the `Widget` class as a container for other widgets eliminates the capabilities of widgets that are intended for use as containers such as `size_hint` and `pos_hint`. From the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html):

> A Widget is not a Layout: it will not change the position or the size
> of its children. If you want control over positioning or sizing, use a
> Layout.

2. When you reference `pos` or `size` of a widget in its `__init__()` method, you will always get the default values of `(0,0)` for `pos` and `(100,100)` for `size`.
3. References to properties (such as `pos` and `size`) in a widgets `__init__()` method use the current values of those properties (see #2 above), and there is no binding to handle changes in those values. So, for example, creating a `Rectangle` in a widgets `__init__()` using the widgets `pos` and `size` will create an unchanging `Rectangle` at `pos` of `(0,0)` and `size` of `(100,100)`.

So, a fix for getting the `ChessBoardWidget` drawn where you expect is to just change the base class of `ChessBoardWidget` to `RelativeLayout`. The nice thing about `RelativeLayout` is that adding a child with the default `pos` and `size_hint` will result in the child (in your case, the `Image`) being drawn with the same position and size as its parent (the `ChessBoardWidget`). Something like this:

```
class ChessBoardWidget(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChessBoardWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0, 1, 0, 1)
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=(self.width, self.height), pos=self.pos)

        self.add_widget(
            Image(source="./data/images/chess-pieces/DarkerGreenGreyChessBoard.png", keep_ratio=True, allow_stretch=True))
```

Note that the green `Rectangle` will still be drawn at the lower left corner of the `ChessBoardWidget` with `size` of `(100,100)`. To fix that, you either need to define the `Rectangle` in a kivy language file or string that gets loaded before the `ChessBoardWidget` gets created. Or you need to set up bindings that will redraw the `Rectangle` whenever the `ChessBoardWidget` gets re-sized.

I believe this is the easiest way to draw the green background, using `Builder.load_string()`:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<ChessBoardWidget>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,1,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: 0,0
            size: self.size
''')

class ChessBoardWidget(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ChessBoardWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # with self.canvas.before:
        #     Color(0, 1, 0, 1)
        #     self.rect = Rectangle(size=(self.width, self.height), pos=self.pos)

        self.add_widget(
            Image(source="./data/images/chess-pieces/DarkerGreenGreyChessBoard.png", keep_ratio=True, allow_stretch=True))
```

Comment: To JOHN ANDERSON ---> THANK YOU SO MUCH!! WOW!!!   This was the most detailed and eye-opening explanation I've ever received at stackoverflow.

Comment: KUDOS to JOHN ANDERSON ---> THANK YOU SO MUCH!! WOW!!!   This was the most detailed and eye-opening explanation I've ever received at stackoverflow.    ====> One more thing though.....my understanding is that all widgets and layouts have a canvas and the image added to the widget is being drawn on the canvas. The 'green' rectangle is supposed to provide a background color to widget/layout, so why does it still appear separately at 0, 0, 100, 100 even after using RelativeLayout as the base class to ChessBoardWidget? Shouldn't the canvas and drawing be coupled as one entity?

Comment: KUDOS to JOHN ANDERSON  !!! (can't tire of writing this...your help is much appreciated!) ===> What is the best way to keep track of the size of the image as it is resized in the splitter?

Comment: KUDOS to JOHN ANDERSON !!!    ===> Note: it turns out the green rectangle "IS" being drawn in the splitter at what would be 0, ,0, 100, 100 in splitter coordinates.